# Spring boot maven pid folder path setup

Tags: java, spring, maven, unix

Here is the `pom.xml` setup:

```
<embeddedLaunchScriptProperties>
    <mode>service</mode>
    <confFolder>./config</confFolder>
    <logFolder>./logs</logFolder>
    <logFilename>${project.artifactId}.log</logFilename>
    <pidFolder>./pid</pidFolder>
    <pidFilename>test.pid</pidFilename>
</embeddedLaunchScriptProperties>
```

The project root folder is `/a/b/c`, however the `test.pid` file is generated in `/a/b/c/pid/c_abc/test.pid.` So why is the `c_abc` subdirectory generated automatically?

The `logFolder` and `logFilename` tags do not have the same issue.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: It might be the version issue but I did not find the solution.